# perl CGI parameters not all showing

Tags: apache, perl

I am passing about seven fields from an HTML form to a Perl CGI script.

Some of the values are not getting recovered using a variety of methods (POST, GET, `CGI.pm` or raw code).

That is, this code

```
my $variable = $q->param('varname');
```

resulted in about half the variables either being *empty* or *undef*, although the latter may have been a coincidental situation from the HTML page, which uses JavaScript.

I wrote a test page on the same platform with a simple form going to a simple CGI, and also got results where onpy half the parameters were represented. The remaining values were empty after the assignment.

I tried both POST and GET. I also tried GET and printed the query string after attempting to write out the variables; everything was in the query string as it should be. I'm using `CGI.pm` for this.

I tried to see if the variable values had been parsed successfully by `CGI.pm` by creating a version of my test CGI code which just displays the 
parameters on the HTML page. The result is a bunch of odd strings like

```
CGI=HASH(0x02033)->param('qSetName')
```

suggesting that assignment of these values results in a cast of some kind, so I was unable to tell if they actually 'contained' the proper values.

My real form uses POST, so I just commented out the `CGI.pm` code and iterated over STDIN and it had all the name-value pairs as it should have.

Everything I've done points to `CGI.pm`, so I will try reinstalling it.

Here's the test code that missed half the vars:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;

use CGI;

my $q = new CGI;

my $subject     = $q->param('qSetSubject');
my $topic       = $q->param('qTopicName');
my $userName    = $q->param('uName');
my $accessLevel = $q->param('accessLevel');
my $category    = $q->param('qSetCat');
my $type        = $q->param('qSetType');


print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

print "<html>\n<head><title>Test CGI<\/title><\/head>\n<body>\n\n<h2>Here Are The Variables:<\/h2>\n";

print "<list>\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetSubject\') = $subject\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qTopicName\')  = $topic\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'uName\')       = $userName\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetCat\')     = $accessLevel\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetType\')    = $category\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'accessLevel\') = $type\n";
print "<\/list>\n";
```

The results of ikegami's code are here:

```
qSetSubject: precalculus
qTopicName: polar coordinates
uName: kjtruitt
accessLevel: private
category: mathematics
type: grid-in
```

**My attempt to incorporate ikegami's code**

```
%NAMES = (
        seqNum => 'seqNum',
        uName  => 'userName',
        qSetName => 'setName',
        accessLevel => 'accessLevel',
        qSetCat => 'category',
        qTopicName => 'topic',
        qSetType => 'type',
        qSetSubject => 'subject',

);

   use CGI;
   my $cgi = CGI->new();
   print "Content-Type:text/html\n\n";

   #print($cgi->header('text/plain'));
   for my $name ($cgi->param) {
      for ($cgi->param($name)) {
         #print("$name: ".( defined($_) ? $_ : '[undef]' )."\n");
         print "$NAMES{$name} = $_\n";
         ${$NAMES{$name}} = $_;
      }
   }

print "<html>\n<head><title>Test CGI<\/title><\/head>\n<body>\n\n<h2>Here Are The Variables:<\/h2>\n";

print "Hello World!\n";

print "<list>\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetSubject\') = $subject\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qTopicName\')  = $topic\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'uName\')       = $userName\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetCat\')     = $accessLevel\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'qSetType\')    = $category\n";
print "<li>\$q->param(\'accessLevel\') = $type\n";
print "<\/list>\n";
```

Comment: You're being very imprecise. Please add [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/Yj5dqXBe) to the top of your script, provide the output, and provide the desired output.

Comment: You did something like `print "$q->param('variable')";` when you should have done `print $q->param('variable');`. (Don't put Perl code in quotes!)

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I was in the wrong section for this post.  Anway, shouldn't perl interpolate the variable in double quotes?

Comment: Ikegami, I used your code and all the variables showed up.  But I don't know why.

Comment: Re "*shouldn't perl interpolate the variable in double quotes?*", Yes, it interpolates `$name`, and it did, but that's not what you wanted to do. You wanted to execute Perl code and print its result.

Comment: I just added the test code I was using. subject, topic and userName were empty.

Comment: Please take a look at [*Markdown Editing Help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You shouldn't use HTML markup if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: thanks Borodin I'll have a look at that.  ikegami, i added the output of your code to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I've done many perl forms and never had a problem like this.

Comment: This has all been very helpful thank you.  Nobody will tell me why my code is behaving inconsistently?

Comment: I'm trying now to incorporate your code but you can see mine up there--why the #@E#% doesn't it work?  I can't figure it out.

Comment: So I tried to use your code and i'm missing vars again.  See, nobody is getting at the evident problem here.  The assignment line crapped out after 4 assignments.  That is, I only got values for 4 of the six.  Meanwhile, the earlier line shows that at each iteration $_ has the correct value.

Comment: @user1064558: I guess you still want an explanation? Please would you clarify your question. I need to be able to relate each version of the code to the output that it produces for you. I'm also unclear what you mean by *ikegami's code*. So if you show a version that is missing output values, together with its output, and then a version with correct output (if you have one) together with the output from that, then I can help. Also, *crapped out* generally means the program died or crashed. Is that what you mean here? If so then please post the error message.

Comment: You should also avoid using *symbolic references*. `${$NAMES{$name}}` dereferences a symbolic reference because `$NAMES{$name}` is a simple string -- the name of the variable. That is very bad practice, and the usual solution is to use a hash instead. Read about symbolic references in [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references). You should also make sure to put `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write. You will also need to declare all of your variables as close as possible to their first point of use.

Comment: Thank you Borodin for your comments.  *ikegami* answered most of questions earlier in this lengthy comments, and he linked to some code he wrote, which I refer to as 'ikegami's code'.

Comment: I had to incorporate it into my code because I never figured out why mine didn't work.  using symbolic references resulted in the least amount of code and I knew how to do it.  I will look into using hashes instead.  Thanks for the tip.  My attempt to use ikegami's code actually DID work--it was tripped up by a cached form that had been subsequently changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving

```
qSetSubject: precalculus
qTopicName: polar coordinates
uName: kjtruitt
accessLevel: private
category: mathematics
type: grid-in
```

so

```
my $category    = $q->param('qSetCat');
my $type        = $q->param('qSetType');
```

should be replaced with

```
my $category    = $q->param('category');
my $type        = $q->param('type');
```

Comment: uh the bit you say i'm receiving was what I received from YOUR code, not mine.  and also I *am* using $q->param('qSetCat') and so on.  Maybe you're looking at the hash i used to help me incorporate your code. I used it to construct symbolic refs to my var names which was a shorter rout then checking each value in $q->param().  Still pecking away at this....  I will for sure post a definitive answer when I get it.

Comment: Re "*was what I received from YOUR code*", I know I wrote it. I have no idea why you mention this. It doesn't matter who wrote it. What matters is that it shows what you are receiving. /// Re "*I* am *using `$q->param('qSetCat')` and so on*", I know. Like I said, you shouldn't be. That's the cause of the error you are having. You should be using `$q->param('qSetCat')` instead because the parameter is named `category`, not `qSetCat`.

Comment: Apologies for this thread...I am returning to a coding project after several years and there were some name/variable mismatches over the thousands of lines of code and 30 or so different files, which mostly accounted for my problems.  There was not one single problem, but several.  Also, a = where there was supposed to be ==.  I finally tracked them all down.  I appreciate the help